# Triggers en MYSQL en PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli, trigger

Tengo una duda. Debo crear un *trigger* para una tabla `peticion` que tiene estos campos:

> id, Fecha, Contador, Asignatura2, Usuario2, Estado2, tippet2

Debo hacer que cuando el campo `Contador` sea `>=8` y el campo `Estado2` de las asignaturas sea `= 2` me modifique el campo `Estado2` a **`Estado2= 3`**.

Hice esto, pero no me funciona.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tr_actualizar_estado
BEFORE UPDATE
ON peticion FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.Contador >= 8 AND NEW.Estado2 = 2 THEN
     set NEW.Estado2 = 3;
  ELSEIF NEW.Contador < 8 AND NEW.Contador >= 1 THEN
    set NEW.Estado2= 2;
  END IF;
END;$$
```

Comment: puedes poner la base de datos con los datos y tabla para ayudarte en todo lo posible

Comment: @JavierG.Raya Perdona mi intrusión, pero cuando edites preguntas o respuestas que ya se ven bien no hace falta que las modifiques con las tres tildes graves (de hecho te equivocas y usas 4) porque si el código ya está identado con el botón `<>` del editor ya es correcto dejarlo asi.  Tan solo tendría sentido hacerlo si hubiera algun fallo de resaltado de sintaxis, y entonces podrias agregar el lenguage con los tres acentos graves. Te lo comento porque estoy revisando  ediciones y cuando son tan solo eso los estoy rechanzando, lo siento.

Comment: perdon es una mania que tengo ya que me estaba liando como esta antes

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema esta en que tu código esta bien pero no cambiar el ***`delimiter ;`*** por lo que seguramente estés llamando archivo este no te va a funcionar.

También si no recuerdo mal cuando te equivocas debes eliminar el trigger si existe para poder volver a ejecutarlo  ***`DROP trigger IF EXISTS tr_actualizar_estado $$`***.

Aparte de eso donde te puse ***`USE BD;`*** añade la base de datos a la que pertenezca la tabla.

```
USE BD; # Añade aqui la base de datos tuya la cual va al trigger
DELIMITER $$
DROP trigger IF EXISTS tr_actualizar_estado $$
CREATE trigger tr_actualizar_estado BEFORE UPDATE ON peticion 
    for each ROW
    BEGIN
         IF NEW.Contador >= 8 AND NEW.Estado2 = 2 THEN
            set NEW.Estado2 = 3;
         ELSEIF NEW.Contador < 8 AND NEW.Contador >= 1 THEN
            set NEW.Estado2= 2;
         END IF;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

En si tu código no esta mal pero te faltaba Usar la base de datos, eliminarlo y el delimiter en si son tontearías por las cuales suelen perder la tarde.

Espero que te haya funcionado saludos.